# Определение вне класса для static const int

Tags: c++

Насколько мне известно, для типа `int` инициализировать статические константные члены можно внутри класса, не вынося определение вне класса:

```
class A {
  static const int x = 42;
}
```

Класс компилируется. Однако если попробовать получить адрес x из другой единицы трансляции, то получаю linker error:`undefined &A::x`. С определением вне класса всё работает без ошибок.

Так нужно ли определение вне класса для `static const int`?

Comment: constexpr можно использовать

Comment: А Вы включаете определение класса в другую единицу трансляции?

Comment: Если надо получить ссылку то надо определять вне класса иначе можно не определять

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Если вы определили статическую константную переменную внутри класса, то фактически в коде не будет использоваться область памяти с данной константой, а будет просто подстановка константы прямо в код.

И адрес несуществующей переменной вы просто не сможете получить. В любом месте программы.

Если бы вы хотели объявить статическую переменную **не** константную, то инициализацию в самом классе вам бы просто не дали сделать. (*не стандарт*) Вам нужно будет определить удалённо данную переменную. И будет вам и память для этой переменной, и адрес.

Если вы не будете искать адрес константы, то можно и не определять в другом месте.

Answer (score 0):

Статические целочисленные переменные можно не определять, если они используются в качестве константного выражения. Начиная с С++17 определение переменной можно сделать прямо внутри класса:

```
class A {
    static inline int const x{42};
};
```

Comment: По-моему, вопрос немного о другом.

Comment: Статические целочисленные переменные , если они используются в качестве константного выражения,  можно было определять  прямо внутри класса всегда, а не только начиная с  С++17

Comment: @ARHovsepyan Статические целочисленные переменные до С++17 определять внутри класса было нельзя. Однако при использовании таких переменных только внутри константных выражений нет необходимости их определять, как я и написал в своем ответе.

Answer (score 0):

Такое объявление `A::x`, как в вашем примере, не является *определением*. Нужно или не нужно предоставлять *определение* для такого члена класса зависит от того, попадает использование такого члена в вашем коде под определение так называемого *ODR-использования* (ODR-use).

Попросту говоря, если требуется, чтобы для `A::x` было фактически выделено место в памяти, то `A::x` придется определить. Если же `A::x` используется только в константных выражениях времени компиляции, то определения не требуется.